# How to move all open Notepad++ files in all views into one single view?

Tags: windows, join, merge, notepad++, display

### The Issue

When you have Chrome browser open, if you have many different "windows" (as in "open in new window" vs "open in new tab") open, as I often do, it is useful to be able to join them all into one single window, leaving each tab intact. I use an extension called **JoinTabs** and it works great. A different extension, OneTab, merges all tabs into one tab by converting the individual tabs into hyperlinks -- ***that is not what I'm trying to do***.

What I'm asking is if Notepad++ has configuration settings, a keyboard shortcut, or a plugin that will accomplish the same thing. By "the same thing", I mean ***not 'merging' all open documents into one document***, but rather merging multiple documents dispersed across multiple Notepad++ instances (windows) into one windows.

#### Example

So, to be ultra clear, lets say I had three Notepad++ instances/windows/views open, and lets refer to them as A, B, and C for ease of discussion. A has 10 files open, B has 3 files open, and C has 5 files open. A working solution must move all open file tabs into window A and remove windows B & C, such that window A now will contain all 18 tabs.

Whenever I search for "join", "merge", or "combine" I keep getting text/document operations instead of view/display operations.

### Research

When I search for this all I find are a bunch of false positives including stuff about:

- Merging files into one
- Merging lines
- Merging all files in a directory
- Using the ['combine' plugin from Heinz](http://www.scout-soft.com/combine/)

FYI: Though it can be a little ambiguous, I've tried to take the ambiguity out of it by clarifying -- with a clear example -- what I'm asking. The 'combine' plugin doesn't do anything close to what I'm asking, and it can easily be seen if one take the time to read the description on the author website which says:

> 3 files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) can be combined to one file

Those are all entirely different than what I'm asking.

We are not after one file ... but rather all files in one window.

Comment: sadly I am facing the same problem, any luck on this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Notepad++ Plugin Manager, there is an entry called `combine`:

[image]

...and based on the plugin's description, sounds like what you are seeking?

I have never used the `combine` plugin, so I have no other details.

Comment: -1 NO. Please read the description where I clearly stated that I was not wanting to join them into one file, but rather one window.

Comment: @halfer 1. Thank you for your comment. My response spans multiple comments (7 parts), so please wait an hour or so before replying. I seek not to contend, but to understand ...

Comment: @halfer 2. I have done my utmost to be nothing but kind whenever responding to commenters (anyone, for that matter) ever since joining the Stack community in 2011, and I take offense at your statement that I was being "deliberately rude" to anyone, which implies that my intent in commenting was to inflict pain and cause hurt to someone who may in fact have been trying to be helpful, but fell short of the mark.

Comment: @halfer 3. I do not use sarcasm or exclamation points unless I'm quoting and I use all caps sparingly -- usually only for content organizations to make my post more scannable. I believe in treating others as you would want to be treated: with respect and a spirit of openness and understanding.

Comment: @halfer 4. If you are referring to Paul T's answer, I don't see how anything in it was "unkind". My response clearly and succinctly states the problem with his answer. Other than maybe saying something like "you solved the wrong problem very well", which might appear sarcastic, I don't see how, given the space limitation, I could have responded any kinder while still communicating why the answer was wrong.

Comment: @halfer 5. Also, his response was as that of one who is trying to answer a bunch of questions quickly to earn participation or community engagement points, without paying attention to the question details. This may not be the case, but either Stack Overflow adheres to requiring questions and answers that are not opinion based, but rather based in demonstrable, provable fact, or I am at fault for not understanding the community rules as well as I thought. If it is the latter, then perhaps anyone can ... (cont)

Comment: @halfer 6. ... post anything they want as an answer as long as it is peripherally-related? For instance, If a poster asks about a solution for Window 10 business edition and takes the extra time to include a meta comment indicating that answers for Windows 10 home edition will not work, are a waste of his/her time, and clog up the question like me too comments do on Microsoft forum threads, how would you suggest that ... (cont)

Comment: @halfer 7. ... one communicate the idea of "wrong and obviously didnt pay attention to the question details" to the answerer and anyone else who might in haste and uncarefulness try to offer similar unuseful-to-the-OP answers? I am eternally the seeker, thus I would really love to know if you have a better way to -- within the limited space afforded by the comment box -- clearly and concisely indicate the problem with the respondent's answer. I do not post this in anger, but rather in confusion and hopefulness. Thank you.

Comment: In short, I think that there's a difference between giving frank and honest feedback to any question, and giving frank and honest feedback to someone answering you (and trying to help you) in particular. Sure, all emotional responses - such as offence - are a matter of opinion, which is why I am helpfully setting my opinion out, hopefully for your benefit. I think it is indisputable that a `-1 NO` is brusque at best. I don't share your view that the answer author was _obviously_ not paying attention - people make mistakes.

Comment: I am willing to accept, given your subsequent response, that you were not setting out to be rude. However, it is hopefully useful feedback that your first comment, on its own, looked exactly like you were seeking to provoke. If you are genuinely looking to afford people respect and openness, then criticism needs to be diplomatic and couched in careful and expansive terms. How to do that is outside of the scope of this site, but I believe it is worth everyone's consideration.